# When Does/Doesn't Clause Order Matter in a (Postgre)SQL Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

(First off, I *swear* I tried searching for this, and even checked the PostgreSQL documentation, but the existence of the `ORDER BY` clause makes finding an answer about any other kind of ordering difficult.)

Everyone knows that SQL statements have an order, and you put (for instance) your `FROM` clause after your `SELECT` clause.  The [PostgreSQL SELECT documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) itself even lists all of every possible clause for a `SELECT`, in order.

However, I thought (and maybe this was based on other SQL databases?) that the order of clauses only mattered for the programmer, or at least mostly only mattered, and that the database itself didn't really care if you put your `LIMIT` before your `ORDER BY`, or vice versa.

So, simple question: does clause order always matter, and the list on the PostgreSQL page must be followed exactly, or does the clause order not matter at all (but your co-workers will look at you funny if you screw it up), or does it matter only sometimes (and if so what's the "rule" for it)?

Comment: Ordering of clauses matters and is defined in the SQL standard.  I can't think of any exceptions to the ordering of clauses in a `SELECT` supported by *any* database.  That is, it is pretty fundamental.

Comment: That sounds like an answer not a comment :)  And yeah, it's been awhile since I actually wrote a SQL statement by hand, so it's very possible my memories are off, but I just wanted to check and see exactly how off (officially) so I could explain it properly to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the order of the clauses in a `SELECT` statement matters.

The documentation you link to shows them in a certain order that is mandatory. Each of these clauses is optional, but if they are there, they must be written in the correct order.

Part of the reason is probably that the SQL language was modeled with the idea to sound like a natural language, and while it is grammatical to say

```
SELECT items FROM shelf WHERE level > 3;
```

it is not grammatical to say

```
SELECT items WHERE level > 3 FROM shelf;
```

Of course SQL is not grammatical in the natural language sense, but I think that this is part of the motivation.

Note also that the (logical) order of execution is different from how the statement is written:

First CTEs are calculated, then the `FROM` clause, then the `WHERE` filter is applied, then `GROUP BY`, then `HAVING`, then the `SELECT` list, then window functions, then `ORDER BY`, then `OFFSET` and `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`/`LIMIT` (I may have forgotten something).

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Just goes to show the damage query builders and ORMs do to your raw SQL knowledge :)